# how to use a picker selection to display an image to a UIImage View

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, uipickerview

I'm trying to assign an image to a UIImage View based on a selection from a picker in the previous view controller. The picker consists of numbers 1-7, so if the number "1" was picked, i want image1 to be displayed on the image view. Some code i have:

This "buttonPressed" moves the scene into the next view controller, as well as declares the selected (select) value from the picker. "spinnerView" is the UIImage View in this second view controller. For some reason nothing will show inside the image view. Quite confused. Please help!

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {

NSString *select = [_array objectAtIndex: [_picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];

if ([select  isEqualToString:@"1"]){
    [spinnerView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"image1"]];
}}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point and stepping through it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In order for us to help you, you'll need to do a bit more debugging on your side first. Does `select` have values that you expect? Is `spinnerView` actually instantiated at this point, or is it `nil`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code can be dramatically simplified by going around the problem in a different way.

1) Create 7 UIImage instances..a put them into NSArray.

```
NSArray *images = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"1"], 
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"2"],
                    .
                    .
                    [UIImage imageNamed:@"7"]];
```

2) Using subscripting to get the correct instance.

```
spinnerView.image = images[[_picker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
```

This simply choses an image with an index that matches the index for the selected row in component.

SOME DEBUGGING CHECKS:

1) check your images by naked eye..are they really all different

2) hardcode the image index from 0-6 to test that each is picked up properly.

```
spinnerView.image = images[6];
```

3) put the index into a local variable before you pass it to array. Do you get the correct index?

Comment: This works except for the fact that no matter what selection i make, the first image always shows.

Comment: Ive been trying everything, heres what my code snippets look like...

problem is.. when that NSLog displays below, 0 is always displayed. Ive literally tried everything and I've hard coded in the images in that last line and it works fine. Im sorry for the crude cope snippet below..

Comment: selection = [_picker selectedRowInComponent:0];

NSLog(@"selection: %ld", selection);

spinnerView.image = images[selection];

Comment: first do not use ivar use self.picker property. then check if there is an instance of picker at all. put a breakpoint on that line and hover over it. Does it have a nonzero memory adress? third is this picker the same picker you see in the screen?

Comment: Any success in fixing it?

Comment: I messed around with it a lot but i did get it to work! thank you!!

Comment: What was the problem?